# Mathematica 10 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, permissions

I am trying to install Mathematica 10 on Ubuntu 16.04. In my folder I had a .sh file, so I used  `chmod +x` and ran it.

During the installation it asks to choose a folder for the installation, but whaterver I type it says:

> Error: Cannot create directory /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0.
>
> You may need to be logged in as root to continue with this
>   installation.

What do I do?

Comment: What is the exact command you used to start the installation?

Comment: Have you used the sudo command for running the installation file *.sh, e.g. "sudo bash installer.sh"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I used ./Mathematica.sh

Comment: Try `sudo ./Mathematica.sh`.. ?

Comment: Concur. Adding sudo will solve the problem.  Enter your password when requested, there will be no feedback, not even spaces, then press enter.